# Uncompress BZIP2 archive

Tags: java, api, compression, bzip2

I can uncompress zip, gzip, and rar files, but I also need to uncompress bzip2 files as well as unarchive them (.tar).  I haven't come across a good library to use.

I am using Java along with Maven so ideally, I'd like to include it as a dependency in the POM.

What libraries do you recommend?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The best option I can see is [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) with this Maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

From the [examples](http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html):

> ```
> FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("archive.tar.bz2");
> FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("archive.tar");
> BZip2CompressorInputStream bzIn = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(in);
> final byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
> int n = 0;
> while (-1 != (n = bzIn.read(buffer))) {
>   out.write(buffer, 0, n);
> }
> out.close();
> bzIn.close();
> ```

Comment: To copy the streams, you can also use Apache Commons IO's [IOUtils.copyLarge](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copyLarge%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Answer (score 4):

Please don't forget to use *buffered* streams to gain up to **3x speedup**!

```
public void decompressBz2(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    var input = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile)));
    var output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    try (input; output) {
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    }
}

decompressBz2("example.bz2", "example.txt");
```

With `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20")
}
```

Comment: Serious difference here!