# Create .gz file in Java which contain couple files

Tags: java, gzip

How to compress in Java several files in one .gz file ?

Comment: GZIP is a stream compression algorithm, it doesn't do file-handling. Are you referring to `.tar.gz`?

Comment: Usually it's better to use ZIP for this kind of thing, unless there is a specific requirement to use .tar.gz.

Comment: @Sergey: It is usually easier to use ZIP (at least from Java code), but I doubt that it's usually better. If the files have similar content, tar.gz provide a much better compression rate than zip.

Comment: @jarnbjo, I meant that it is better because it's easier and more "standard". For best compression, tar.gz is much better of course, especially when there is a lot of small files, but usually it isn't that important. Another funny approach would be to create a ZIP with no compression, then compress it using gzip. I haven't seen it in real life, but the good point is that it can be accomplished using the standard Java library.

Answer (score 4):

You must somehow join them before gzipping. Gzip can compress only one file, so most frequent solution is to `tar` files first and them `gzip` newly created tar.

Comment: See this question for information on programmatically tar'ing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java