# Extract tar file

Tags: java, android, extract, tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I extract a tar file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java)

I have tar file in my res/raw folder,

How can I extract this file to data/data/my.project.name/folder ?

Can You help me ?

Comment: Related: [How do I extract a tar file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java)

Comment: @miku  Why you marked this question as a duplicate? Many of the java libraries for Tar make use of java.nio... Android does not have full support

Comment: @user60108, you make a very good point. But it would have been helpful, if the OP included a bit more background into the question and maybe also the reason the standard approach don't work (e.g. NIO not available, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your assets folder instead; Android has functions to open assets as if they are files.