# How do I expand a compressed tar file in Android 2.2 or higher

Tags: android, gzip, tar, compression

Given a compressed tar file (created by gzip) on the SDCard I need to expand/uncompress it within an Android app. The tar file contains pictures, text, and subfolders with files under the subfolders. I want the expansion/decompression to maintain the directory hierarchy.

I've tried using commons-compress-1.2.jar but Android reports issues with the .jars ArchieveException.

I'm want to implement something like:

File inputFile = new File("path to the downloaded tar");

File outputDir = new File("Directory on the SDCard to uncompress to");

DecompressThis(inputFile, outputDir);

Comment: may be this one helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java

Comment: I tried that, it is where I encountered the ArchieveException because Android can't handle the .jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't a trivial solution as I'd hoped. I put together several pieces of public code/library and created an AsyncTask that does what I'm looking for.

Thanks for the input/help from everyone.

Comment: I can post the code (place where suggestions welcome) for others.

Comment: That would be nice indeed if you could post your solution. I'd like to open tar files from my app