# Is there a pre-rolled way to Unpack a Tar using pure Java API?

Tags: java, tar

I have a tar archive. I'd like to unpack it and turn it into a set of files.

I don't want to roll my own solution.

**I would like to avoid adding another library to my program (apache commons compress).**

Is there any pre-made method for doing this using the basic java API?

(Bold added above because people are suggesting that my question is a duplicate of this question: [How do I extract a tar file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java), but all of the answers there suggest 3rd party libraries. The answer to this question is either: Yes, here is the link to the java/oracle API, or No, this is not a part of the standard java library.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract a tar file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Every answer in that thread talks about using external libraries, which I specifically exclude in my question.

Comment: gzip is part of java SE - if you aren't using SE you need to be more specific.

Comment: What are we talking about GZip for? :confused:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any support for unpacking tars in the standard library. I don't believe that functionality exists as of Java 8.