# Unable to extract nested tar within zip file i.e. a .tar file inside a zip file and so on

Tags: java, algorithm, archive

I have gone through the link of how to extract a `.tar` file and several link on SOF using Java.
However, I didnt find any which can relate to my concerns which is `multilevel or nested .tar/.tgz/.zip file`.
my concern is with something like below

```
Abc.tar.gz
    --DEF.tar
          --sample1.txt
          --sample2.txt 
    --FGH.tgz
          --sample3.txt
-sample4.txt
```

This is the simple one which I can give here . As it can be in any compressed combination with the folder like `.tar` inside `.tar` and `.gz` and again `.tgz` and so on....

My problem is I am able to extract till the `first level` using `Apache Commons Compress library`. that is if `Abc.tar.gz gets extracted then in the destination/output folder its only DEF.tar available` . beyond that *my extraction is not working*.

I tried to give the *output of first to the input to the second on the fly* but I got stuck with FileNotFoundException. As at that point of time output file would have not been in place and the second extraction not able to get the file.

Pseudocode:

```
public class CommonExtraction {
   
    
    TarArchiveInputStream tar = null;
    if((sourcePath.trim().toLowerCase.endsWith(".tar.gz")) || sourcePath.trim().toLowerCase.endsWith(".tgz")) {
        try {
        tar=new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourcePath))));
        extractTar(tar,destPath)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        }
        
        Public static void extractTar(TarArchiveInputStream tar, String outputFolder) {
        try{
        TarArchiveEntry entry;
        while (null!=(entry=(TarArchiveEntry)tar.getNextTarEntry())) {
        if(entry.getName().trim().toLowerCase.endsWith(".tar")){
        final String path = outputFolder + entry.getName()
        tar=new TarArchiveInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))) // failing as .tar folder after decompression from .gz not available at destination path
        extractTar(tar,outputFolder)
        }
        extractEntry(entry,tar,outputFolder)        
        }
        tar.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        
        Public static void extractEntry(TarArchiveEntry entry , InputStream tar, String outputFolder){
        final String path = outputFolder + entry.getName()
        if(entry.isDirectory()){
        new File(path).mkdirs();
        }else{
        //create directory for the file if not exist
        }
        // code to read and write until last byte is encountered
        }
        
    }
```

Ps: please ignore the syntax and all in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try (InputStream fi = file.getInputStream();
    InputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(fi);
    InputStream gzi = new GzipCompressorInputStream(bi, false);
    ArchiveInputStream archive = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzi)) {

        withArchiveStream(archive, result::appendEntry);
}
```

As i see what .tar.gz and .tgz is same formats.  And my method withArchiveEntry is:

```
private void withArchiveStream(ArchiveInputStream archInStream, BiConsumer<ArchiveInputStream, ArchiveEntry> entryConsumer) throws IOException {
    ArchiveEntry entry;
    while((entry = archInStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        entryConsumer.accept(archInStream, entry);
    }
}

private void appendEntry(ArchiveInputStream archive, ArchiveEntry entry) {

    if (!archive.canReadEntryData(entry)) {
        throw new IOException("Can`t read archive entry");
    }

    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        return;
    }


    // And for example
    String content = new String(archive.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that class `GzipCompressorInputStream` is part of Apache Commons?

Comment: Yes.
org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream

Comment: @George_A Thanks for your reply. sorry, to try this, i need to understand it clearly. you want me to try the above one in the start itself ? where i am checking the file type```(.tar.gz or .tgz)``` not in the ```extractTar``` or ```extractEntry``` method(referring to my code snippet).However, i am confused with your method ```withArchiveStream(archive, result::appendEntry)``` what does it will contain ? and why you are passing the boolean ```false``` parameter in the ```GzipCompressorInputStream``` And also I have a doubt whether it will check all scenario or just I am able to see .gz type ?

Comment: I`m expand my answer

Comment: @George_A sorry but I am confused here. I am trying to understand whether its completely new approach or this i can use in my pseudocode provided. However, I am not able to find what is the ```result``` and appendEntry uses as  you are not calling that method. Can you please elaborate a bit your sample code and if i can use this in my sample code provided. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive problem, so you can use recursion to solve it. Here is some pseudocode to show how it can be done:

```
public class ArchiveExtractor
{
    public void extract(File file)
    {
        List<File> files; // list of extracted files

        if(isZip(file))
            files = extractZip(file);
        else if(isTGZ(file))
            files = extractTGZ(file);
        else if(isTar(file))
            files = extractTar(file);
        else if(isGZip(file))
            files = extractGZip(file);

        for(File f : files)
        {
            if(isArchive(f))
                extract(f); // recursive call
        }
    }

    private List<File> extractZip(File file)
    {
        // extract archive and return list of extracted files
    }

    private List<File> extractTGZ(File file)
    {
        // extract archive and return list of extracted files
    }

    private List<File> extractTar(File file)
    {
        // extract archive and return list of extracted files
    }

    private List<File> extractGZip(File file)
    {
        // extract archive and return list of extracted file
    }
}
```

where:

- `isZip()` tests if the file extension is zip
- `isTGZ()` tests if the file extension is tgz
- `isTar()` tests if the file extension is tar
- `isGZip()` tests if the file extension is gz
- `isArchive()` means `isZip() || isTGZ() || isTar() || isGZip()`

As for the directory where each archive is extracted: you are free to do as you want.
If you process `test.zip` for example, you may extract in the same directory as where the archive is,
or create the directory `test` and extract in it.

Comment: thanks. I believe```public void extract(File file)```, here file will be ```input file/source file```. But I have a doubt regarding the destination path where it gets extracted. And also I didnt get about ```isArchive()```.As we have separate flag for each file type then what does``` isArchieve flag``` is used for ? does this for all file type at once ? Following, how to check for the different file type at the destination path once it start get extracting.

Comment: during the implementation of the above logic,i am stuck at the logic of extract the each file type and ```return list of extrcted files```.As most of the extrcted methods will be of type void and if i am changing to list of Files,it will not allow me as during extrction i have to go till write level of each file type. Can you suggest

Comment: @Trips Not sure to understand your problem. Every time you extract a file, you know where you extract it. So you can keep (or create) a `File` object that represents that file.

Comment: if you see my pseudocode provided,```extractEntry``` this is simple static and void method which will be having read/write logic until the last byte of file will read. A/c to the recursive logic if i will extract the file,i am expected to return the list of files extracted.my concern is what i can return apart from null as here only read/write logic will be present.

Comment: @Trips Create an `ArrayList<File>`;  for every processed `extractEntry`, add a file to it; return the list.

Comment: @Trips See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556307/12763954) for an example.

Comment: again stuck with the starting issue where I was getting the error of FileNotFoundException. From the above link , I am getting the error ```java.io.FileNotFoundException <input file path> (The system can not find the path specified)``` at the line ```final TarArchiveInputStream debInputStream = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", is)``` eventhough the input file path is available and I dont see any issue with the permission. It seems some locks is happening at this level.

Comment: @Trips Are you sure the exception is not raised by the line just before? The file is opened by `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);`.

Comment: sorry, my bad. thanks.  It was failing at the above steps. However, I have figured out this error. But, Now I am getting ```java.io.IOException: Truncated TAR archive``` at the line ```IOUtils.copy(debInputStream, outputFileStream)``` in the ```unTar()``` method.  any suggestion.